# How do I correctly push foreach items to array list?

Tags: javascript

I added storage items to my array list. But i cant use my array in another function. I see on console values. But i cant use.

```
this.storage.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (key == 'favoriteStory') {
    //console.log("value", value);
    this.item = value.toString();
    this.myItems.unshift(this.item);
  }
})
```

Comment: What is `this` referencing?

Comment: Please provide the value of `this.storage`. At least in native JS `forEach` is a method of an array

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to push element to an array. You can use it on a single element of course, but I made it on arrayOfNames which includes few names.

```
var array = [];

var arrayOfNames = ['Tom', 'Cindy', 'Thomas'];

arrayOfNames.forEach(name => {
    array.push(name);
})

console.log(name); // ['Tom', 'Cindy', 'Thomas']

for (let name of arrayOfNames) {
    array.push(name);
}

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
    array.push(arrayOfNames[i]);
}
```